# Download all photos sent to me on Google Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

You can find lots of Google search results about how to download all photos sent *to you* on Hangouts by one person.  Unfortunately, within the last year Google changed something about how Hangouts works, and now this trick no longer works.

I have an older relative who sent me lots of cat pictures on Hangouts over the past year. I want to download all of these and make a photo album.

What is the easiest way to do this?